# Keeping track of data source for records

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, data-warehouse

I have a bunch of flat files from different vendors that I import monthly and I would like to keep track of what records come from which file.

Currently:

```
CREATE TABLE Fact.Order
(
     Id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
    ,OrderId INT NOT NULL
    ,VendorId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Vendor (Id)
    ,OrderTypeId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES OrderType (Id)
    ,SaleDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL
    ,Amount MONEY NOT NULL
);
```

File tracking tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [File]
(
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    VendorId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES Vendor (Id)
    FileHash BINARY(20) NOT NULL,
    FileSize BIGINT NOT NULL,
    ModifiedDate DATETIME2 NOT NULL,
    FileRecordCount INT NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
    UpdatedDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
    IsDelete BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT UQ_Files_FileHash_IsDelete UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
    (
        FileHash,
        IsDelete
    ) WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)
);

CREATE TABLE FileImport
(
    Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FileId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES [File] (Id),
    OrderTypeId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES OrderType (Id),
    ImportRecordCount INT NOT NULL,
    CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
    UpdatedDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
    IsDelete BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
);
```

Would it be preferable to keep the `FileImport` key inside `Fact.Order` table or should the data be put into its own table?

Edit:

So far I decided to drop the `VendorId` from the `File` table, so now it only stores information about the files.

Then I created metadata tables for each fact table containing a unique identifier to relate back to the business key.

```
CREATE TABLE File.Order
(
    OrderId INT NOT NULL,
    VendorId INT NOT NULL,
    FileId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES File (Id),
    CreatedDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
    UpdatedDate DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT GETUTCDATE(),
    IsDelete BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    CONSTRAINT UQ_File_Order_OrderId_VendorId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    (
        OrderId,
        VendorId,
        FileId
    )
)
```

Comment: So you're snowflaking the the File and FileImport tables off of the Vendor dimension?

Comment: Well the File table is for metadata more than actual business data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would **not** store the FileImport fk in the Fact.Order table. It has nothing to do with the Fact.Order itself.

If the import records need to be queried on a regular basis, then create another logging table. Keep in mind that if the File.Order record is modified or removed in the future, you will lose consistency in your recording.

If it is for historical records, in case of audit, then log to a file and keep the file elsewhere.

Comment: I decided to create a second table that stores the source primary key along with the file metadata. Check my question.